# How to make function run, then wait for user input, then another function run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a problem with figuring out how to make a function run - and then wait for user input (I.E: If user selects to share location), and then run another function. When the "getUserLocation" function runs, the "addLocationArrayToMap" function runs before the user has a chance to make any input on the alert window.

Some debugging returns "userPos is not defined" which makes me think that my guess as to why it's not working is accurate..?

Code below:

```
var markers =[];
var myLocationIconArray = [];
var infoWindowContentString = '';
var addInfowindow;
var distanceArray = [];
var addInfowindow;

function runAll() {
    getUserLocation(addLocationArrayToMap);
}

function getUserLocation() {    
    map.setOptions({draggable: true, zoomControl: true, scrollwheel: true, disableDoubleClickZoom: false});

// Another function that deletes 'dummy' markers before adding Real Markers to the map
    deleteMarkers();

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            centerPos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            map.setCenter(centerPos);
            addMarker(centerPos);
        }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        //Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, map.getCenter());
    }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, defaultPos) {
    infoWindowContentString = "Sorry, we can't get your location.";
    addInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: infoWindowContentString
        });
    map.setCenter(defaultPos);
    addMarker(defaultPos, addInfowindow);
}


function addMarker(location, addInfowindow) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: yourLocation,
        draggable: false,
        clickable: true
    });
    if (addInfowindow == null) {
        var myLocationInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "Your location"
        });
        myLocationInfowindow.open(map, marker);
        myLocationIconArray.push(marker);
    } else {
        myLocationIconArray.push(marker);
    }
}


function addLocationArrayToMap() {
    userPos =  new google.maps.LatLng(centerPos.lat, centerPos.lng);

    for (var z = 0; z < dabblersArray.length; z++) {    
// dabblersArray is an array of Lat & Lng coords.
        dabblerLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(dabblersArray[z].lat, dabblersArray[z].lng);
        calculateDistance(userPos, dabblerLocation);

        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: dabblersArray[z],
            map: map,
            icon: dabblers,
            draggable: false,
            clickable: true
        }));
// Some logic to add the distance from the user and the dabblersArray as an alert window above each marker - haven't done this yet. 
    }
}

function calculateDistance(userPos, dabblerLocation) {
    distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(userPos, dabblerLocation);
    distanceArray.push(distance);
}
```

Comment: Apologies if it's hard to follow or I've missed something - it's almost midnight and I'm quite tired :/

Comment: You pass it to method `getUserLocation(addLocationArrayToMap);` but do nothing with it: `function getUserLocation() {...}`. Nothing in your code as i can see it call `addLocationArrayToMap()`. So it is hard to figure out your statement: `function runs before the user has a chance to make any input on the alert window.`

Comment: Yes, I realised that this was a mistake this morning. As I said above - apologies if it's hard to follow as it was late, and I was tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has no concept of making a user wait. The way to accomplish this is using callbacks, exactly like `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` exemplifies. It has success and error callbacks, which you are already using.

And you're already passing in `addLocationArrayToMap` to `getUserLocation`, but not using it. It should be invoked as a callback function in the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` success handler. Mission accomplished.

```
function runAll() {
    getUserLocation(addLocationArrayToMap);
}

function getUserLocation(onComplete) {    
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            //Your logic...

            //Invoke callback 
            onComplete();
        }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, map.getCenter());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will give it a go tonight when I'm home from work.